# Can I send timer, when timer time is equal 0 via a Websocket Gateway in nestJS

Tags: mongodb, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

***Through postman I connected to the timer-update event, but still I do not receive the timer object when time = 0***

***time.service.ts***

```
    @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_SECOND)
      async updateRemainingTime() {
       const timers = await this.timerModel.find({
           isActive: true,
           remainingTime: { $ne: null },
    });

    for (const timer of timers) {
        if (timer.isInfinite) {
            timer.remainingTime += 1;
            timer.pricePerHour += timer.price / 60;
        } else if (timer.remainingTime > 0) {
            timer.remainingTime -= 1;
            timer.pricePerHour += timer.price / 60;
            if (timer.remainingTime === 0) {
                this.socketServer.emit('timer-updated', timer);
            }
        }
        else if(timer.remainingTime === 0) {
            await this.clear(timer._id);
            this.socketServer.emit('timer-expired', timer);
        }

        await timer.save();
    }
   }
```

**AND THIS IS MY timer.gateway.ts**

```
@WebSocketGateway()
export class TimerGateway implements OnModuleInit {
@WebSocketServer()
server: Server;

onModuleInit() {
    this.server.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log(`User with ${socket.id } id is connected!`);
    });
  }
}
```